# How to share the same functions, that operate on variables of two different classes, between the two classes in SwiftUI?

Tags: class, swiftui

I have two classes, one is ItemToEdit and the other is ItemToDisplay.
Then two struct View, one is Buttons and the other is Expression.
In the structs the environmentObject is correspondingly ItemToEdit and ItemToDisplay, which came from the two @StateObject in Calculator View, that contains Buttons and Expression.

On ItemToEdit there is a @Published var itemToEdit, and Buttons View modify that variable with a lot of steps operated by a lot of functions.

Expression is a combination of nested Views built on itemToDisplay.
On ItemToDisplay there is a @Published var itemToDisplay, which get updated with itemToEdit after all the modifications of Buttons View. This is to avoid that every modifications on itemToEdit produce multiple updates per frame on Expression View.

```
struct Item {
    var operations: [String]
    var numbers: [String]
    var lists: [String]
}

class ItemToEdit: ObservableObject { //defines an environmentObject in a stuct "A"
    @Published var itemToEdit: Item = Item(operations: [], numbers: [], lists: []) //gets updated from struct "A" in multiple steps

    //here there are a lot of functions
    func edit() {
        itemToEdit.operations.append("multiply")
    }
}
 
class ItemToDisplay: ObservableObject { //defines an environmentObject in a stuct View "B"
    @Published var itemToDisplay: Item = Item(operations: [], numbers: [], lists: []) //gets updated to itemToEdit at the end of the edit steps
    
    // -> here there are some functions that has to be also on ItemToEdit, where has to be applied to itemToEdit
    func getNumberIndex() -> Int {
        itemToDisplay.operations.firstIndex(of: "divide") ?? -1
    }
}

struct Calculator: View {
    
    @StateObject var edit: ItemToEdit
    @StateObject var display: ItemToDisplay
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Expression() //here there are a lot of nested View built on itemToDisplay
            Buttons() //here there are buttons that initiates a lot of functions that acts step by step on itemToEdit
        }
        .environmentObject(edit)
        .environmentObject(display)
    }
}
```

The problem is that both classes ItemToEdit and ItemToDisplay has to use some functions that are equal but operates correspondingly on itemToEdit and itemToDisplay variables, where should I put these functions and how to make them operate on the right variable?

Comment: Could you give an example of such function and how it differs in implementation between the two classes?

Comment: These functions that I want to share are just the same between the two classes, and do not modify the independent variable, which is itemToEdit and itemToDisplay. The only difference is the independent variable and these functions just build up some return values based on logic applied to the independent variable (of type Item). One example is the function getNumberIndex which simply returns firstIndex of one operations in Item. That function is applied to itemToEdit in the class ItemToEdit, but I need to have the possibility to apply that also to itemToDisplay in the class ItemToDisplay.

Comment: Looks to me like you need a protocol containing those functions and then your classes should conform to that protocol and you could also create default implementations in a protocol extension if you don’t want to implement all functions for every conforming class.